# How do I change a specific hotkey?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Bacially, theres this hot key to change windows which is ctrl+windows+left. I want to change it to the F1 key. I cannot find any way to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map
<kbd>F1</kbd>
to
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>:

```
F1::Send, ^#{Left}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)